# How can I find locked table & its row in Oracle 12C using V$LOCK and V$SESSION tables alone

Tags: oracle, find, locking

We have a banking application with Oracle 12c using ORCL locking mode. Our application is creating UL type locks in V$LOCK table and one sample lock is shown as below

SQL> SELECT ADDR,KADDR,SID,TYPE,ID1,LMODE,CTIME FROM V$LOCK WHERE TYPE='UL';

ADDR             KADDR                   SID TY        ID1      LMODE      CTIME

---

00007FFA1F65BC18 00007FFA1F65BC90        131 UL 1073741845          6       1808

SQL>

I am trying to find the relevant table & row locked by the above lock. Some how our application is not using v$locked_object table for locking mechanism. Hence, please help me to find the table & row being locked in my situation

Regards,
Manohar[image: Lock Picture]

Answer (score 1):

UL means User Lock, that is ne created by using DBMS_LOCK package. So there's no underlying table associated with it. For other object locks, you can use V$LOCKED_OBJECT